# Getting sum using EL and JSP

Tags: jsp, sum, el

```
<%
    double sum = 0.0;
%>
<c:forEach var="user" items="${page.content}">
    <%
        sum += $user.grade;
    %>
    ${user.grade}
</c:forEach>
```

I want get the sum of all `user.grade`. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix JSTL with scriptlets.  Actually, don't use scriptlets at all.

```
<c:set var="sum" scope="page" value="0.0"/>
<c:forEach var="user" items="${page.content}">
    <c:set var="sum" scope="page" value="${sum + user.grade}" />
    ${user.grade}<br/>
</c:forEach>
```

Better yet, do your summation in a controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@page import="org.springframework.data.domain.Page" %>
```

I import Page first, than I can do it in Java.

```
<%
Page p=(Page)request.getAttribute("page");
List<User> content= p.getContent();
double sum = 0.0;
for (User user: content){
    sum += user.getGrade();
}
%>
```

And output:

```
<div><%=sum %></div>
```